# Differences between "Wie folgend" and "wie folgendes"

Tags: meaning, difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "wie folgend" und "wie folgendes", z. B.:

> 1. Meine Arbeitszeiten sind wie folgend:
> 2. Meine Arbeitszeiten sind wie folgendes:

Comment: If I am not wrong, if there is a noun after this, you shoud also be careful for the article. I mean, for example, wie folgendes Beispiel. However, to answer your question, I would say *wie folgt* but I am not sure.

Comment: I would use "wie folgt/folgendermaßen", too. In Duden they have the example: "die Formel lautet[,] wie folgt (folgendermaßen)" http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wie_Konjunktion_Vergleich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first sentence "*wie folgend*" is used as a synonym of "*as follows*", however I think even the given example is a bit bad and -my feeling says- a verb is missing. I would prefere using "*folgendermaßen*" or "*wie folgt*" -with the same meaning- as suggested by @Iris in her comment. A better formulation here would be (verb in bold letters):

> Meine Arbeitszeiten sind *wie folgt* (or *folgendermaßen*) **dargestellt**/**beschrieben**:

And here an exmaple of a sentence using "*wie folgend*":

> Die Frage möchte ich *wie folgend* beantworten:
>
> I'd like to answer the question *as follows*:

Even here I would prefere using "*wie folgt*" or "*folgendermaßen*". You can take a look at other examples [here](http://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/wie+folgend.html) IMO the first example is among the best uses for "*wie folgend*".

The second sentence is wrong, "*wie folgendes*" requires a noun. A better or more correct formulation  using "*folgende*" (instead of"*folgendes*") is:

> Meine Arbeitszeiten sind folgende:

"*folgende*" is used here as a synonym of "*the following*".

Examples for sentences using *wie folgende*/*wie folgender*/*wie folgendes*:

> *Wie folgende* Grafik zeigt ist unser Umsatz gestiegen.
>
> *As* shown by *the following* chart, our sales have risen.
>
> Die Datenliste kann auch einfach sortiert und neu aufgebaut werden *wie folgendes* Beispiel zeigt.
>
> The data list can be also easily sorted and redisplayed *as the following* example shows. ([Source](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/wie+folgendes+beispiel.html))

Comment: `Folgendes sind meine Arbeitszeiten` - shouldn't it be `Folgende`?

Comment: @MartinRosenau I can't see a reason why! Note I'm a native speaker who didn't grow up in Germany so my theoretical grammar background is about zero even if I don't commit much errors! Folgendes refers to "die Arbeitszeiten"

Comment: Quite simple: You might say "Folgendes ist mein Hobby:" (= singular) or "Folgende sind meine Hobbies:" (= plural). "Arbeitszeiten" is plural. However as a native speaker I would say that everyone would put the "folgende" at the end and not at the beginning of the sentence: "Meine Arbeitszeiten sind folgende:"

Answer (score 4):

They are both used incorrectly, even though "wie folgend" is often seen as a (too close) translation of "as follows". However, this should be translated with "wie folgt" or "folgendermaßen". "wie folgende(r/s)" should be followed by a noun.

Answer (score 3):

The second one is wrong. *Folgendes* is a neuter declined form, so it has to be followed by a neuter noun.

> Meine Arbeitszeiten sind [so] wie folgendes Blatt beschreibt: